# Dynamic dictionary value without additional function call

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of timestamps

```
timestamp = time.time()
timestamps[random_element] = timestamp
```

Normally now the dictionary will return timestamps when asked, however, I would like it to return the amount of time since the timestamp. So that when I execute the following line:

```
timestamps[random_element]
```

I would like to get

```
time.time() - timestamp
```

rather than just

```
timestamp
```

Note that I'd rather avoid declaring and referencing new functions. In my opinion, it would be a huge waste to call a function for just one subtraction.

EDIT:
As coldspeed and DeepSpace have pointed out the subclassing is in fact slower  (about 30%), seemingly independent of dictionary size and amount of calls made to the dictionary. This is probably borderline off-topic, but I'd like to know why this is the case. Appreciate the insights

```
time() - timestamps[randint(0,9)]:   10.2322190305
subclassed_timestamps[randint(0,9)]: 13.268092648
```

The subclassed dict is this:

```
class MyDict(dict):
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return time() - dict.__getitem__(self, key)
```

Edit 2:

Lambda function is what i was looking for. Significantly faster than subclassing, unfortunately slower than time() - timestamps[element], but it does what I wanted.

Code:

```
for i in range(10000):
  normal_dict[i]= time()
  subclassed_dict[i] = time()
  lambda_dict[i] = (lambda x,y: x - y, time())
  sleep(0.002)

def normal_d():
  for i in range(1000):
    x = time() - normal_dict[555]

def subclassed_d():
  for i in range(1000):
    x = subclassed_dict[555]

def lambda_d():
  for i in range(1000):
    x = lambda_dict[555][0](lambda_dict[555][1])

print "lambda_timestamps[randint(0,9)]:     {}".format(timeit(lambda_d, number=10000))
print "time() - timestamps[randint(0,9)]:   {}".format(timeit(normal_d, number=10000))
print "subclassed_timestamps[randint(0,9)]: {}".format(timeit(subclassed_d, number=10000))
```

This consistently brings the solution with lambda as a faster option, compared to subclassing.

```
lambda_timestamps[randint(0,9)]:     2.19382280125
time() - timestamps[randint(0,9)]:   0.962934452287
subclassed_timestamps[randint(0,9)]: 3.92690390754
```

Comment: `time.time() - timestamps[random_element]` Is literally the only way. I'm not aware of being able to attach call backs that are run on returned data automatically - you do that yourself.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ He might as well subclass `dict` and define a custom `__getitem__`.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want.  Since `time()` changes constantly, you have to call it every time you want that time interval.  To get the accurate time, you have to reference it whenever you make the access.  Are you trying to eliminate the call, or merely avoid the *text* of the call in some portion of your code?

Comment: @DeepSpace True... did not consider subclassing... however that might constitute "declaring and referencing new functions"... OP's words... they don't want that it seems.

Comment: Nice answers, but what is the question?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want to write code without writing code. Whether or not that is possible is another question :)

Comment: "huge waste to call a function for just one subtraction." But it's not just one subtraction, it's also the call to `time.time()`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Subclassing could work, as I don't want to call an *additional*/*new* function. Creating a custom __getitem__ doesn't increase the amount of function calls as far as I'm aware. Only the __getitem__ will be called either way.

Comment: @EdwinKravčenka This assumption is wrong.

Comment: @EdwinKravčenka Do you actually have a working code for which you concluded function calls are the battleneck? If not, you are wasting your time with (extreme) premature optimization.

Comment: I'm not sure how subclassing is okay but not a side function call. But you can look at: https://pastebin.com/BiMS1hCV where I've typed up an example of how to do it.

Comment: Nothing is a bottleneck here, I'm simply exploring possibilities on my own free time for no actual gain other than trying things out. I've set an arbitrary goal and I'm trying to accomplish it.

Comment: @Prune I'm not trying to eleminate the time() call, I'm trying to combine the call with the request for the value from the dictionary, so that 1) text of the call is eliminated and 2) there is no slowdown due to said combination. Which is why I want to avoid writing a new function which would just get called to then call time().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lambda function stored alongside the timestamp is what I was looking for. Please understand that this wasn't a practical need, just an arbitrary goal of getting the time passed without 1) explicitly subtracting every time and 2) without using a separate named function.

```
timestamps[indx] = (lambda x: time() - x, time())

x = timestamps[indx][0](timestamps[indx][1])
```

I understand this hurts readability, but this was a purely theoretical question, not for a practical application, so that is not a concern. I'm just exploring Python :)

Comment: Subclassing `dict` is still the better option

Comment: Theoretically speaking it will use too much memory to store every unnamed lambda function (the reference) in every key of dict, 72 bytes per function. There will be still a function call: dict[key](). I really like this question. Where do you store timestamp itself?

Comment: The timestamp itself is with the lamba function. It's  a tuple who's first element is the lambda and second element is the timestamp, put there on creation.

The reason i like having lambda function with a direct reference there is that there's firstly no name resolution and on top of that it's clear in the dict itself what is being done with the element. Maybe I'm not giving back just the difference, the lambda doesn't *necesserily* have to be the time()-timestamp difference. subclassing dict or writing another function obfuscates that a little.

Comment: @ElisByberi It won't use too much memory as the dictionary is of size 128 with the values being a list of up to roughly 10 elements. Worst case I'd be storing 1280 references, which is very little memory for the machine in question. That being said - the entries are removed within a couple of seconds of being placed there, so realistically it's never going to even exceed 1000entries. 72kb is perfectly fine.

All that being said for my actual implementation I'm referencing named functions, because I actually need significantly more things to be done. This is just a theoretical question :)